# Bash can't find scripts in $PATH

Tags: bash, environment-variables, path

I'm setting up a completely new, fresh Ubuntu 16.04 Minimal system, and have run into a weird problem. Even after adding `$HOME/bin` to the `$PATH`, `bash` can't seem to find any of the scripts in it, at least for `root`.

I have logged out several times and even restarted the machine once. The path is being set by a one-line script in `/etc/profile.d`: `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"`.

```
root@Pioneer ~ # echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/root/bin
root@Pioneer ~ # ls -la /root/bin
total 36
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb  6 16:04 .
drwx------ 8 root root 4096 Feb  6 16:03 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  174 Jan  5  2017 newuser
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  236 Nov  3  2015 own
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   87 May  6  2017 re-dns
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   57 May 10  2016 re-ftp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   89 Oct 20  2015 re-mail
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   42 Oct 19  2015 re-smb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   65 Oct 19  2015 re-web
root@Pioneer ~ # newuser
-bash: newuser: command not found
```

`/root/bin/newuser` works, as does `cd /root/bin && ./newuser`.

There are no trailing spaces in the name:

```
# ls -lb /root/bin/newuser
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 174 Jan 5 2017 newuser
```

Root's home is indeed `/root`:

```
# getent passwd root
getent: root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

Comment: And presumably `/root/bin/newuser` works as expected, right?

Comment: It is Ubuntu. How do you run as root? Do you use `sudo -s` or `sudo -i`? Maybe it works better if you use  the latter command, `sudo -i`.

Comment: `/root/bin/newuser` works, as does `cd /root/bin && ./newuser`.

Comment: This is not Ubuntu, this is Ubuntu Minimal — a bare-bones, command-line only distribution, and I log in as root directly.

Comment: getent: `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash`

Comment: `ls -lb /root/bin`: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 174 Jan  5  2017 newuser` No trailing spaces.

Comment: I suppose a better test would have been `ls -l /root/bin/newuser`; sorry for the spam.

Comment: What is the output of `strace -e stat  bash -c "newuser" 2>&1 | grep /root/bin`? Do you see `/root/bin/newuser` there?

Comment: Since that `newuser` script is so small, would you mind showing what it contains?  And also let us know whether you have a `newuser` _shell function_ or _alias_.

Comment: `type -a newuser` would illustrate Kusalananda's point above

Comment: What if there is some unprintable character in `$PATH`? You cannot spot it with `echo $PATH`; you need `printf '%s' "$PATH" | xxd` or so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [terdon](/users/22222/terdon) for the tip; by using `strace -e stat bash -c "newuser" 2>&1 | grep /root/bin` I discovered that an invisible carriage return had somehow wedged itself before the the closing quote mark in the profile script, making the actual path `/root/bin\r`. I erased and re-typed the path and it works now.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you manage to wed it there? Was the text copied from a Microsoft Windows program?

Comment: Yes. I was using a Windows PC to remotely setup a new Linux server while copying parts of config from an older one, and since edits went through windows Notepad, that must be how the CR got in there.